# How to enter matrices in block matrix format?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Example:
I have a matrix $R = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & \mathbf{t} \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $ where $A$ is 3-by-3 and $\mathbf{t}$ is 3 by 1. Or in Mathematica

```
 A={{1,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,-1,0}};
 t={1,1,1}
```

I would like to be able to use a form of block matrix notation / entry and subsequently find the inverse of R.

**Question: Is this possible?**

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You're looking for [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html). For your example matrices,

```
 R = ArrayFlatten[ {{A, {t}\[Transpose]},{0, 1}} ]
 (*
 => {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
 *)
```

The construct `{t}\[Transpose]` is necessary for `ArrayFlatten` to treat `t` as a column matrix.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then to find $\boldsymbol{R}^{-1}$, you run

```
Inverse[R]
(* 
=> {{1, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
*)
```

Comment: beat me by 5s...

Comment: He was also asking for the inverse - could add this for completeness.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, done!

Comment: @acl, it's a testament to how much we've been waiting for these types of questions when 3 of the top users jump on it within seconds of each other.

Comment: This point about `{t}\[Transpose]` being necessary is important and subtle: Mathematica (to its credit) does *NOT* finesse the fact that vectors must be either `1 x n` or `n x 1` matrices, that is, explicitly either row or column vectors. Pretty much everything else (including my beloved Golub & VanLoan) does (tho G&VL have the grace at least to say they do). I find the conceptual hygiene forced by Mathematica to be refreshing and helpful.

Comment: Fair warning to others, this didn't work for me. All my blocks were vectors of the same size (in a sparse array).  `ArrayFlatten` did give me a consistently dimensioned array, but it put every element in its own list. (Where `a` should have been, it put `{a}`.) The other solution, where I could use Ctrl+Enter and Ctrl+, worked though.

Answer (score 30):

The keyboard commands 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to enter this format.

You can also use the menu `Insert > Table/Matrix` to create a table of specified size with placeholders.

See [Entering Tables and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html).

---

Depending on the meaning of the question, this may have some bearing:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: beat you to it. :P

Comment: **LOL at the pity vote.**

Comment: I meant, I beat you to posting the "correct" answer. Although, I posted the result he wanted, and you posted the entry method. Win for both of us.

Comment: Not a pity vote.  If you don't post this, I would have edited it into @rcollyer's answer.  It's much more convenient to enter matrices like this (see my screenshot).

Comment: @Szabolcs, I have mixed feelings of entering matrices that way. For a simple matrix, like the OP's, then I prefer just typing it out. If it's much larger, then this route is better, especially getting structure correct.

Comment: @rcollyer Recently I saw someone give input to NDSolve that way, and I really liked it --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWJ3.png

Comment: @Szabolcs, it definitely has its merits.