# Add a sub-matrix of zeros in big matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix of size $24\times24$ composed by 8 $3\times3$ submatrices in a diagonal way. I want to add a matrices of zeros ($3\times3$) between the sub-matrices, so the final matrix would be of size $48\times48$. I appreciate your help.

Real question:

Let's say that I have matrices in this way

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{A} & \mathbb{0} & 0 \\
0 & \mathbb{B} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbb{C} \\
\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{D} & \mathbb{0} & 0 \\
0 & \mathbb{E} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbb{F} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
being $\mathbb{A}\ldots\mathbb{F}$ $3\times 3$ matrices. The zero's there also correspond to $3 \times 3$ matrices of zeros. The idea is to combine them in the following way:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{A} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathbb{D} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbb{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{E} & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\mathbb{C} & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\mathbb{F} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Thus the final size of the, let's say, "big matrix", would be twice as the original ones. When I use your answer, it give me a single matrix with some numbers, not block of numbers as I want

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/761/5, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/5

Comment: @rm-rf I do find it amusing that if you follow that chain, I have the earliest answer. :)

Comment: @Alejandro in that case, see [(3558)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3558). I'm not going to vote to re-open just so that we can close as a duplicate of a different question, but do let us know if this still doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand the distinction you're making; matrices are just blocks of numbers, and an answer should give you an enlarged matrix. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you @rcollyer, it seems the code is taking the first element, let's say $A[1,1]$, but not the whole matrix $\mathbb{A}$. I don't know if it clarifies the question.

Comment: I see the problem. Whether I can fix it quickly, is a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have you matrix in component form, i.e. you have it broken into submatrices, then it is straightforward to construct a block diagonal matrix of any size.

```
Clear[BlockDiagonal]
BlockDiagonal[a : {_?MatrixQ ..}] :=
 ArrayFlatten[
  DiagonalMatrix[Range[Length@a]] /. i_Integer?Positive :> a[[i]]]

(* Convenience notation *)
Unprotect[CirclePlus];
a_?MatrixQ ⊕ b__?MatrixQ := BlockDiagonal[{a, b}]
Protect[CirclePlus];
```

For convenience,

```
Clear[ZeroMatrix]
ZeroMatrix[dim_Integer?Positive] := ConstantArray[0, {dim, dim}]
ZeroMatrix[dims : {_Integer?Positive, _Integer?Positive}] := 
 ConstantArray[0, dims]
```

Which is used as follows:

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
B = {{e, f}, {g, h}};
A ⊕ ZeroMatrix[3]⊕B
```

[image]

**Edit**:

Per the comments, if you want to interlace the blocks from two different matrices, you can either specify the blocks individually, as above, or you can make use of a feature of `SparseArray` to capture the blocks automatically.

```
Clear[BlockMatrixRiffle];
BlockMatrixRiffle[A_?MatrixQ, B_?MatrixQ]:=
Module[{nonzA, nonzB},
    nonzA = FindClusters[SparseArray[A]["NonzeroPositions"], Method -> "Agglomerate"];
    nonzB = FindClusters[SparseArray[B]["NonzeroPositions"], Method -> "Agglomerate"];
    BlockDiagonal@Riffle[
        A[[##]]&@@@Map[Span[Min[#], Max[#]]&, Transpose/@nonzA, {2}],
        B[[##]]&@@@Map[Span[Min[#], Max[#]]&, Transpose/@nonzB, {2}]
    ]
]
```

(**Edit 2**: changed clustering method to Agglomerate which is hierarchical, and more appropriate for this case.)

`SparseArray` only stores elements that are different from a common base which is usually set to zero. So, when you turn a block diagonal matrix into a `SparseArray` you can retrieve the non-zero positions by

```
SparseArray[A ⊕ B]["NonzeroPositions"]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}} *)
```

(Note: this will not find zero blocks, so if those exist, then some other method must be used.)  Now, we use `FindClusters` to group them into blocks:

```
FindClusters[%, Method -> "Agglomerate"]
(* {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}}} *)
```

From there, I turn them into min/max ranges for use in `Part`:

```
Map[{Min[#], Max[#]}&, Transpose /@ %] 
(* {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 4}}} *)
```

So, when I `Apply` `A[[##]]` to the above, I get the equivalent of

```
{A[[{1,2}, {1,2}]], A[[{3,4}, {3, 4}]]}
```

for both the matrices supplied to `BlockMatrixRiffle` which then interlaces the two matrices.

```
mat1 = Table[a[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}] ⊕ Table[b[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
mat2 = Table[c[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] ⊕ Table[d[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
BlockMatrixRiffle[mat1, mat2]
```

[image]

Note, if the number of blocks in `B` exceeds the number of blocks in `A`, those extra blocks will be ignored.  But, if the reverse is true, multiple copies of the blocks from `B` will be included in the result. This can be prevented by a little extra processing, but I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks rcollyer for your answer. I'm wondering in make something more "simple", but I'm not sure ho to do it: I have two matrices, same size (24x24), and they are build by submatrices again 3x3. I want to construct a new matrix from both such that first entry (a matrix 3x3) comes from the first matrix, the second entry for he second matrix, and so on. Basically construct a big array of size 48x48 and put both matrices in that way. Thanks again

Comment: @Alejandro, You can use `Riffle[]` for that purpose.

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo I added a method that auto-extracts the non-zero blocks and interlaces them together.

Comment: @J.M. check out the edit.

Comment: Thanks again rcollyer..I tried to use it, but it doesn't work!. It seems that I need to define somwhow that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are constructed block-wise

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo Define, not work. What is it doing? If you are using matrices that are not block diagonal, it won't work, but if they are, I'm curious what it is doing, instead.

Comment: @rcollyer I edit the original question with the problem I found. Thanks again

Comment: @Alejandro, to clarify: you have the two block-diagonal matrices, but not the $3\times 3$ blocks themselves?

Comment: Yes, I have the block-diagonal, and also the blocks ($3 \times 3$ matrices), they are just numbers

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo I fixed the code for `BlockDiagonalRiffle`.

Comment: Almost @rcollyer, the size of the matrices is 24 (8 matrices $3 \times 3 $),now is putting 4 consecutive elements of the first matrix, and after 4 of the second one.

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo I see. It appears `FindClusters` is not robust at that size. I will look at it later when I have time.

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo the key is apparently using the appropriate clustering algorithm. I added `Method -> "Agglomerate"` to `FindClusters` and it seems to work. It will even find off-diagonal blocks. Of course, `BlockDiagonalRiffle` only works correctly with block diagonal matrices, but that is a detail. Try it out, and let me know if it stands up to your testing.

Comment: Thanks again @rcollyer, it works but just for the first component: it gives correctly $\text{diag }=(\mathbb{A}_1,\mathbb{B}_1)$ but after that it puts the other elements of the first matrix, and after the rest of the second one: $\text{diag }=(\mathbb{A}_1,\mathbb{B}_1,\mathbb{A}_2,...,\mathbb{A}_n,\mathbb{B}_2,\mathbb{B}_n)$. I don't know why The  `BlockDiagonal@Riffle` is acting only inf the first element of each matrix.

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo are you using the function `BlockDiagonalRiffle` or are you using `BlockDiagonal@Riffle`? Also, try restarting the kernel, and see if that changes anything. If that doesn't work, post two small matrices that it doesn't work with and I'll go from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8793/discussion-between-alejandro-guarnizo-and-rcollyer)

Comment: @rcollyer BlockMatrixRiffle has been removed from Mathematica 11? Even the display(`mat1`) is coming with `{{1[1, 1], 1[1, 2]}, {1[2, 1], 1[2, 2]}}\[CirclePlus]{{b[1, 1], b[1, 2]}, {b[2, 1], b[2, 2]}}`, i.e. with \[CirclePlus] not just the display as you showed. Mathematica11? How to go about these problems?

Comment: @L.K. they're not part of Mathematica, the code for them is up above.