# Entering block matrices, general case doesn't work

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I want to enter several matrices at different positions in blocks.
There is already a very similar answer here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3562/6138

I thought that simply generalizing this function, would yield the correct result. But something seems not to work.

This is my function:

```
fmetmat[A_?MatrixQ, C_?MatrixQ, D_?MatrixQ, pos_] := 
 SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{1, 1} -> A, {1 + pos, 1} -> 
 Transpose[C], {1, 1 + pos} -> C, {1 + pos, 1 + pos} -> D}, 
  Dimensions[A] + pos*Dimensions[D]];
```

But what I get for any integer value of `pos` is always:

[image]

I would like to be able to fill the Matrix in this way, so that if I leave holes in between they show up in the end.

I would like to have, for:

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dmat = IdentityMatrix[5]
```

And `pos=7`, the following output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Does somebody understand the logic here and can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have described twice what you don't want, but you have not described what matrix structure you do want.

Comment: Thanks @bills  I uploaded now the desired input and desired output and removed my useless function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is a way:

```
am = IdentityMatrix[3];
cm = {{c, c, c, c, c}, {d, d, d, d, d}, {e, e, e, e, e}};
dm = IdentityMatrix[5]

ArrayFlatten[
  Normal[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> w[am], {1, 6} -> w[cm], {6, 1} -> 
       w[Transpose@cm], {6, 6} -> w[dm]}, {6, 6}]] /. 
   w -> Sequence] // MatrixForm
```

where `w` is just a wrapper to allow `SparseArray` to parse.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept this. It works really well, This little trick of the wrapper w is pretty nice!