# sparse array with list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

i'm trying to populate a sparse array with lists in certain positions, i tried the following code,

`A = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; 0 <= j - i <= 1 -> Avk, {10, 10 + 1}];`

where Avk is 2x2 matrix, but mathematica yields that the assigned value must not be a list. i want the result to be like

[image]

where Avk and 0 are a 2x2 matrices (here is an example of dimension (3x4)), but the actual problem is (124x126) matrix.

Comment: As Mathematica tells you, this is not possible. Elements of a sparse array cannot be arrays themselves. It would be better if you asked about the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: Are you trying to make a four dimensional sparse array?  That is not the same thing as a two-dimensional sparse array with array elements.

Comment: @Szabolcs No it's just a 2 dimension matrix, as you can see in the image, it's a 3x4 matrix with elements are 2x2, in the end i need to do ArrayFlatten so this would be a 6x8 matrix ( i hope did well to describe my problem)

Comment: You can use the answer to the following question, of which this is a possible duplicate: [Entering block matrices, general case doesn't work](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65999/entering-block-matrices-general-case-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Jens thanks man it was a great reference it worked as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

> ... because my matrix is (214x216) so it's impossible to assign all these values one by one.

```
(* your 62  2X2 matrices av1 through av62 *)
avmat = Array[Subscript[Row[{av, #}], ##2] &, {62, 2, 2}]; 

sa = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> avmat, Band[{1, 3}] -> avmat}];
Dimensions@sa
(* {124, 126} *)
sa[[;; 20, ;; 20]] // MatrixForm (* display a portion of sa *)
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Perhaps you can use  `Band`:

```
avm1 = Array[Subscript[av1, ##] &, {2, 2}];
avm2 = Array[Subscript[av2, ##] &, {2, 2}];
avm3 = Array[Subscript[av3, ##] &, {2, 2}];

sa = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> {avm1, avm2, avm3}, 
                  Band[{1, 3}] -> {avm1, avm2, avm3}}];
sa // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or

```
af = ArrayFlatten[{{avm1, avm1, 0, 0}, {0, avm2, avm2, 0}, {0, 0, avm3, avm3}}];
af // MatrixForm
(* same picture as above *)
```

Comment: yes man that works for the example, but the problem is that i need  a dynamic code, because my matrix is (214x216) so it's impossible to assigne all these values one by one

Comment: so `k` goes from `1` to `62`?

Comment: yes you can say so, if i took k goes from 1 to 62, the finale matrix would be (124x126) since each element of the matrix is a (2x2) matrix

Comment: it was helpful,