# Joining matrices together

Tags: matrix

Given the following matrices (where $n$ can be any integer number, It is just for a general dimension of my space):

```
n = 5;
A = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1, 1}]
B = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1, n - 1}]
F = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n - 1, n - 1}]
```

I want to have a full-matrix $c$ defined as:

$
c = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
B & F
\end{pmatrix}.
$

I have tried using `Join` and `ArrayFlatten`, however I cannot do it.

Besides this, how could I impose that $F$ is a symmetric integer-random matrix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 5;
A = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1, 1}];
B = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1, n - 1}];
F = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n - 1, n - 1}];

{A, B, F}
```

> {{{2}},
> {{5, 1, 8, 1}},
> {{1, 9, 7, 1}, {5, 2, 9, 6}, {2, 2, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 7, 1}}

#### [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

You can use `Transpose@B` in the second block and `ArrayFlatten`:

```
c = ArrayFlatten[{{A, B}, {Transpose @ B, F}}]

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ c
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  2 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 1 \\
>  5 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 1 \\
>  1 & 5 & 2 & 9 & 6 \\
>  8 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
>  1 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

#### `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix ``

```
c1 =  SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{1, 1} -> A, {1, 2} -> B, 
  {2, 1} -> Transpose @ B, {2, 2} -> F}]

Normal @ c1 == c
```

> True

See also: [this answer by OlexandrR](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3562/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19780/125).

#### [`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html)

To use  `ArrayReshape` we need to process the second row block as follows:

```
c2 = ArrayReshape[{A, B, Transpose @ {Transpose @ B, F}}, {n, n}]

c2 == c
```

> True

**Note:** to see why we need the more complicated form to use `ArrayReshape` make `B` a symbolic matrix

```
B2 = Array[b, {1, n - 1}];
```

and compare

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ ArrayReshape[{A, B2, Transpose @ {Transpose @ B2, F}}, {n, n}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  2 & b(1,1) & b(1,2) & b(1,3) & b(1,4) \\
>  b(1,1) & 1 & 9 & 7 & 1 \\
>  b(1,2) & 5 & 2 & 9 & 6 \\
>  b(1,3) & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
>  b(1,4) & 3 & 2 & 7 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

with what you get with the simpler/ more elegant form:

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ ArrayReshape[{{A, B2}, {B2, F}}, {n, n}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  2 & b(1,1) & b(1,2) & b(1,3) & b(1,4) \\
>  b(1,1) & b(1,2) & b(1,3) & b(1,4) & 1 \\
>  9 & 7 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
>  9 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
>  4 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Update:** A function to construct  random symmetric integer matrices:

```
ClearAll[ranSymIntMat]
ranSymIntMat[range_, d_] := Symmetrize[2 #] - IdentityMatrix[d] # & @ 
  UpperTriangularize[RandomInteger[range, {d, d}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
Row[MatrixForm @ ranSymIntMat[9, #] & /@ Range[2, 7], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

```
ArrayReshape[{{A, B}, {B, F}}, {n, n}]
MatrixForm@%
```

> {{9, 6, 9, 3, 6}, {6, 9, 3, 6, 7}, {3, 8, 2, 8, 2}, {5, 5, 2, 8, 
>     8}, {3, 1, 9, 2, 1}}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  9 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 6 \\
>  6 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 7 \\
>  3 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 2 \\
>  5 & 5 & 2 & 8 & 8 \\
>  3 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 6):

> Besides this, how could I impose that $F$ is a symmetric integer-random matrix?

Here is one way to do it.

```
SeedRandom@2
n = 5;
H = PadRight[
   TakeList[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, n^2], Range[n - 1]], {n - 1,
     n - 1}];
F = H + Transpose@H - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@H
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  9 & 5 & 5 & 1 \\
>  5 & 6 & 8 & 2 \\
>  5 & 8 & 5 & 1 \\
>  1 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Or use the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59679/generating-random-symmetric-matrix)

```
  H = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n - 1, n - 1}];
    upper = UpperTriangularize[H, 1];
    diag = DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal@H];
   F=diag + upper + Transpose[upper]
```

Or this

```
 H = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n - 1, n - 1}];
lower = LowerTriangularize[H];
diag = DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal@H];
F = lower + Transpose[lower] - diag
```