# Printing Block Matrices

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I have a 2D matrix, such as:

```
d=2;
M=Array[a, {d^2,d^2}];
```

and I would like to print it in a way which emphasizes its dxd block matrix structure. If `MatrixForm` had a `Dividers` option like `Grid`, then this is what I would use. But it doesn't. The first thing I tried was:

```
With[
    {div={False, Join[Table[False, {n, d - 1}], {Dashed}], False}},
    {{Grid[M,Dividers->{div,div}]}}//MatrixForm
]
```

where the `{{stuff}}//MatrixForm` is simply to get the parentheses.

The problem with this is that if your matrix is big (d>2) and certain entries of your matrix are big expressions, then they do an ugly line wrap thing. To counter this, I call `{{TableForm[#]}}&` on each element of the matrix first:

```
With[
    {div = {False,Join[Table[False, {n, d - 1}], {Dashed}],False}}, 
    {{
        Grid[Map[TableForm[{{#}}] &, M, {2}],Dividers -> {div, div}]
    }} // MatrixForm
]
```

but this is a hack. So I suppose my questions are:
What Form do `TableForm` and `MatrixForm` use on each of their elements, and can I use this here? I've tried `StandardForm` but that's not it.
Next, is there in general some better way to do what I am trying to do?

**Edit:** As requested, here is an example that illustrates the "ugly line wrap thing":

```
d = 3;
M = Table[Expand[(a + b)^RandomInteger[4]], {i, d^2}, {j, d^2}];
```

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-to-enter-matrices-in-block-matrix-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of a better example I am going to suppose that you just need `ItemSize -> Full`:

```
With[{div = {False, Append[Table[False, {d - 1}], Dashed], False}},
  {{Grid[M, Dividers -> {div, div}, ItemSize -> Full]}} // MatrixForm
]
```

Code for convenience that shows wrapping without that option:

```
ClearAll[a, x]

d = 3;
a[7, 2] = Expand[(1 + x)^10];
M = Array[a, {d^2, d^2}]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I put my edit in before I saw your example, and I see we came up with similar examples. The matrix I actually want to print is too unwieldly to copy here.

Comment: @Ian Glad I could help.  If you want the items to all the be same size to make a nice regular table you can use `ItemSize -> All`.