# Building a matrix in block matrix format

Tags: matrix

Now, I'm aware of the threads existing about this question such as:

[How to enter matrices in block matrix format?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-to-enter-matrices-in-block-matrix-format)

[How to form a block-diagonal Matrix from a list of matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/how-to-form-a-block-diagonal-matrix-from-a-list-of-matrices)

But I wasn't able to find the solution to my problem there. I need to make a matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 &I\\
0 & C_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My problem is that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are of different sizes! $C_1$ is of size 30 and $C_2$ is of size 48. So one would expect the following code to work:

```
MatrixForm[ArrayFlatten[{{c1, IdentityMatrix[30], 0}, {0, c2}}]]
```

or maybe

```
MatrixForm[ArrayFlatten[{{c1, IdentityMatrix[30], ConstantArray[0,{18,18}]}, 
{ConstantArray[0,{30,30}], c2}}]]
```

But neither actually works!

#### Edit

I ended up using J.M's answer:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{c1, PadRight[IdentityMatrix[30], {Automatic, 48}]}, {0, c2}}]]
```

Comment: Why not `ArrayFlatten[{{c1, IdentityMatrix[30]}, {0, c2}}]`?

Comment: this doesn't work either :(

Comment: Try `ArrayFlatten[{{c1, PadRight[IdentityMatrix[30], {Automatic, 48}]}, {0, c2}}]]` then.

Comment: Awesome! That worked!

Comment: Yes they are both square. C1 and C2 are companion matrices and i'm trying to make the Jordan rational normal form. I don't think there is a problem, I might be wrong though

Comment: How can I enter the following Diagonal block matrix instruction in Mathematica version 7?
diag[I,1/3*I,1/5*I,....,1/(2*M+1)*I]

Answer (score 3):

```
m30 = ConstantArray[3, {30, 30}];
i30 = IdentityMatrix[30];
m48 = ConstantArray[4, {48, 48}];
m12 = ConstantArray[0, {48, 12}];

Transpose@Join[m30, i30]~Join~Join[m12, m48, 2]
```

Comment: I ended up using an anwer provided above but thank you for taking the time anyway!

Comment: They are different answers, J.M.'s follows the idea that C1 and C2 have no columns in common - which can be inferred from your sketch above. Eldo's answer maintains the fact that `I` is an identity matrix.  You can't have both: if `I` is an identity matrix, then the shape described doesn't make sense