# Joining 4 matrices into one

Tags: matrix

I have four square matrices 5x5 and I need to join them into one 10x10. I tried various commands like Join, Append, Union and none work properly. Any advice?

Comment: Check `KroneckerProduct` and `ArrayFlatten`. BTW, it would be better if you provide a MWE.

Comment: Thanks. KroneckerProduct is something else.

Comment: `KroneckerProduct` can be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter matrices in block matrix format?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-to-enter-matrices-in-block-matrix-format)

Answer (score 8):

```
(matrices = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, {2, 2, 5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
ArrayFlatten[matrices] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

`KroneckerProduct` seems to be deemed as something else, however I would say that all roads lead to Rome.

```
fiveByFive = RandomInteger[100, {4, 5, 5}];
posMat = {{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}};
MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {posMat, fiveByFive}] // Total
```

---

**Update**

`posMat` can have an alternative definition

```
posMat = SparseArray[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}} -> 1, {4, 2, 2}]
```

Comment: Here is the problem. I am using Mathematica 4 and it doesn't have the commands listed above. What should I do?

Comment: @user1765636 For future questions, it would be a good idea to post your Mathematica version directly into the question. Version 4 is almost 18 years old and this constrains the possible solutions considerably.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use version 4, you might try `Flatten` like this:

```
matrices = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 5, 5}];
Flatten[Partition[matrices, 2], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
```

However, I am not sure if this use of `Flatten` was already established in version 4. Just give it a try.

Another alternative is

```
Join @@ (Join[Sequence @@ #, 2] & /@ Partition[matrices,2])
```

Or maybe

```
Transpose[
 Join @@ Transpose[
   Join @@@ Transpose[Partition[matrices, 2]], {1, 3, 2}]]
```

will do.

Comment: This is not what I need. I have 4 matrices n1, n2, n3, n4. Please write the command for me.

Comment: What about some example data? The more effort you put into your question the likelier you get the answer you need.

Comment: I have 4 5x5 matrices n1, n2, n3, n4. I need to combine them into one 10x10 matrix with n1 in the top left corner, n2 in the top right, n3 in the bottom left and n4 in the bottom right, and I am using Mathematica 4. I got above example of using join, what should I put in this command instead of parameter 'matrices'? I tried {{n1, n2},{ n3, n4}}. It doesn't work. I also tried Flatten[{{n1,n2},{n3, n4}},2]. It doesn't work. If I change 2x3, then I get one-dimensional list of 100 items. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I edited the answer. Try `matrices = {n1, n2, n3, n4}`.

Comment: Mathematica 4 does not understand two join commands, because it repeats one of them in the printout. Any other ideas?