# How to dynamically define matrix with blocks in subdiagonals?

Tags: functions, matrix, sparse-arrays

```
Clear[V0, V1, V];
Nm = 10;
\[Sigma] = {({
    {0, 1.},
    {1., 0}
   }), ({
    {0, -I},
    {I, 0}
   }), ({
    {1., 0},
    {0, -1.}
   })};(*Pauli-spin matrices*)
V0 = Normal[
   SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Table[V[n], {n, 1, Nm - 1}], 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> Table[ConjugateTranspose[V[n]], {n, 1, Nm - 1}]},
     Nm]];
V[n_] := IdentityMatrix[2] + I ({n, n, n}. \[Sigma]);
V1 = ArrayFlatten[V0];
```

Above is the code with fix size. In this way I can use arrayFlatten to define the normal matrix. See example below:
[image]

However, the thing will change if I use a variable input (See below).

```
Clear[V0, V1, V]
\[Sigma] = {({
    {0, 1.},
    {1., 0}
   }), ({
    {0, -I},
    {I, 0}
   }), ({
    {1., 0},
    {0, -1.}
   })};(*Pauli-spin matrices*)
V0[Nm_] := 
  Normal[SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Table[V[n], {n, 1, Nm - 1}], 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> Table[ConjugateTranspose[V[n]], {n, 1, Nm - 1}]},
     Nm]];
V[n_] := IdentityMatrix[2] +  I ({n, n, n}. \[Sigma]);
V1[Nm_] := ArrayFlatten[V0[Nm]];
```

If I evaluate above, then I got error as follows:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `\[Sigma]`? Please post complete code.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for pointing out. Sigma are pauli matrices as shown in the code now.

Comment: What is `α`? If it is not necessary to show the problem, it is better to remove it, but if it is needed, can you, please, provide such detail of its definition? Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian Sorry,  α doesn't matter so I removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions of the same solution.  First, using a general 2x2 matrix along the subdiagonal

```
ClearAll[v]
v[Nm_] := Block[{array, band},
  array = With[{mat =
      Normal@SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> Array[band, Nm - 1], Nm]},
    ArrayFlatten[mat /. {0 -> ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], band[n_] :>
        n{{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}}]];
  (array + ConjugateTranspose[array])
  ]

v[4] /. Conjugate[b_] :> Superscript[b, "*"] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The code creates a variable `array` with the 2x2 matrices along the subdiagonal.  The code takes advantage of the `Band` notation in `SparseArray`.  `band` is an indexed variable that stands for 2x2 matrices.  `band` variables are replaced by actual 2x2 matrices.  Zeroes in the matrix are also replaced by 2x2 matrices.  Then the complex transpose is added to produce the superdiagonal.

Here is a version that uses the Pauli matrices.  This should reproduce the results of an earlier version of the question.  This version uses `ComplexExpand`, which assumes that $\alpha$ is a real number.

```
ClearAll[v]
v[Nm_] := Block[{array, subdiag, b},
  subdiag = Array[b, Nm - 1];
  array = Normal@SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> subdiag, Nm];
  array = array /. {0 -> ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]};
  array = array /. b[n_] :> Cos[α] IdentityMatrix[2] +
      I n Sin[α] Total[Array[PauliMatrix, 3]];
  array = ArrayFlatten[array];
  (array + ConjugateTranspose[array]) // ComplexExpand]

v[4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you think the ArrayFlatten should automatically do all the things above to make it more intuitive?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am editing the second version of the function to make each step clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the first case does not through an error, but `SparseArray` expectes the correct dimensions of the array as second argument. So `V0` should read as follows:

```
V0[Nm_] := SparseArray[{
    Band[{3, 1}] -> Table[V[n], {n, 1, Nm - 1}],
    Band[{1, 3}] -> Table[ConjugateTranspose[V[n]], {n, 1, Nm - 1}]
    },
   {2 Nm, 2 Nm}
   ];
```

The result is a matrix of dimensions`{2 Nm, 2 Nm}` and you do not have to apply `ArrayFlatten` afterwards.

Comment: This is not correct since what I want to do is really arrayFlatten the Block Matrices V[n] (each of them is 2x2 matrix). By using arrayFlatten, I can convert the Block matrices into the normal matrix. See the example in my post.

Comment: See this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-to-enter-matrices-in-block-matrix-format

Comment: Please see updated code. The point is to use `Band[{3, 1}]` instead of `Band[{2, 1}]`.

Comment: Ok, now this works. Thank! But from my point of view, the indices should not depend on the size of the block and should be automatically handled by Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is somewhat counterintuitive.

Comment: Also, the size of the sparse matrix is depending on the size and number of Block matrices, which should be calculated accordingly.