# Create Matrix with both matrices on the diagonal AND the upper diagonal?

Tags: matrix, mathematica-online

[image]

I do know how to do this for matrices on the diagonal, but I can't figure out how to do this for matrices on both the diagonal and the upper diagonal. Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of `Fold` you could have used `ArrayFlatten[{{a,0,0,0},{0,b,0,0},{0,0,c,0},{0,0,0,d}}]`. Then replace `0`'s above the diagonal with matrices, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Can you give an example of a (small) matrix you'd like to create?

Comment: Code not images please! A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `Band` can be used:

```
foo[diag_,upperdiag_] := SparseArray[{
      Band[{1,1}]->diag,
      Band[{1,Dimensions[diag[[1]]][[2]]+1}]->upperdiag}] // Normal;
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
r[dimx_,dimy_] := RandomInteger[{1,9},{dimx,dimy}];
foo[{r[3,3],r[2,2],r[2,3],r[3,2]},{r[3,2],r[2,3],r[2,2]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: thankyou @user293787, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a comment: Your question risks being closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-to-enter-matrices-in-block-matrix-format). If you are interested in keeping the question open, you should explain in your question (you can still edit!) why you think it is not a duplicate, or agree that it is a duplicate, whatever the case may be. Also, usually one should post code, not screenshots of code. Have a nice day!